# Magento Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception: Unable to connect via TLS

Tags: php, email, magento, cron

On Magento version 1.9.1 I am using a custom module where I need to send the mail by cron..
I am also using Aschroder SMTP Extension.
The testing for mail sending works fine within Magento Aschroder extension.
Server setting:

```
mail.mydomain.com
port:587
security:TLS
authentication:plain
```

the related module code is like

```
public function sendExpiryNotification()
    {

        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
     ->setToEmail('mytest mail id')
     ->setBody('Body of the Automated Cron Email Goes Here')
     ->setSubject('Subject: Cron Task  '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
     ->setFromEmail('sender id')
     ->setFromName('Store name')
     ->setType('html');

    $mail->send();
  }
```

Now when I running the cron.php manually from command line:
I am getting these corn error logged in Magento Database:

```
Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception: Unable to connect via TLS in /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:213
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#1 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#2 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#3 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email.php(48): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#4 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/community/Meanbee/VIPMembership/Model/Observer.php(249): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email->send()
#5 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): Meanbee_VIPMembership_Model_Observer->sendExpiryNotification(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#6 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#10 /var/www/clients/client2/web200/web/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#11 {main}
```

and in my server mail.log

```
Jan  3 16:20:08 server2 postfix/submission/smtpd[23306]: lost connection after STARTTLS from server2.mywebsolutions.co.in[69.197.135.186]
Jan  3 16:20:08 server2 postfix/submission/smtpd[23306]: disconnect from server2.mywebsolutions.co.in[69.197.135.186] ehlo=1 starttls=1 commands=2
```

Need some help on what I am doing wrong here.